# Let's pick t-shirt tagline!

Tags: discussion

As you all [know](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6430/code-review-top-user-swag), we're very close to sending SWAG to some of you! One of items you'll get is this awesome T-shirt!

[image: DAMN AWESOME T-SHIRT]

As you can see, below the logo we placed a very short tagline: "*Making code slightly less wrong.*". This is the tagline [that was proposed in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=25627837#25627837). But not everyone is in chat. So we'd like you guys to give us your proposals and vote to pick the one we’re gonna print.

Here're rules:

- Add proposals as answers to this meta post.
- One proposal per answer.
- We’ll close the list and voting in January 15th, 2016 @ 1:37pm EST. The answer with the biggest number of upvotes on that date wins and goes to printing. Caveat: this is subject to approval from <s>the design team overlords</s> me.

And here're guidelines:

- It should be a one-liner. So it can't be too long (or too short :)). Probably similar in length to "Making code slightly less wrong."... more or less... :)
- Yea, I think that's it.

Comment: Can they use.. colourful language? (like "Crap").

Comment: @DanPantry I'd say it depends on context :)

Comment: I can haz my name on it ? :)

Comment: @EmilyL. umm.. I don't think so :)

Comment: # I survived the [The Mission](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/999/call-of-duty-were-on-a-mission/) If only you could put links on t-shirts.

Comment: Where can I find a file with that image? I can print it on a shirt myself...

Comment: @KonradViltersten well the Code Review logo is a copyrighted property of Stack Exchange Inc. ..I wouldn't mess with that ;-)

Answer (score 32):

## Making code slightly less wrong.

Just so the ones loving the existing line can vote to keep it.

<sub>[Credits: @Zak](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=25627837#25627837)</sub>

Comment: I think I really like it.

Comment: -1 because [less wrong](https://www.google.fr/search?q=less+wrong) is (already used as) a tagline of the Skeptics community (e.g. Skeptics.SE)

Comment: @ChrisW and that means that the Skeptics community has some patent on using "less wrong"?

Comment: @ChrisW I can't find any reference to "less wrong" being included in the tagline on skeptics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely Merely that I wouldn't choose e.g. "pro choice" or "pro life" or whatever as a tagline either. I'm simply saying that this phrase already has some associations which you may or may not be aware of, and which are more-or-less unrelated to this site.

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely Also code isn't supposed to be wrong at all, is it? So isn't "slightly less wrong" a bit of false humility, in this context?

Comment: Perhaps this could be revised to 'Making good code slightly less wrong'?

Comment: @Mast Or "Making working code slightly less wrong"

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely "working" isn't catchy. I like the proposed tagline for it is funny and also makes reviewers humble, and highlights the fact that there is no perfect code :)

Comment: -1 Isn't the whole basis of this site that there's a difference between "good" and "not wrong"?

Comment: @BenAaronson Reviews need to be reviewed too, so as long as a review hasn't been reviewed, you can only assume that the code is slightly less wrong.

Comment: @BenAaronson How about "Making code slightly less bad." ?

Comment: @SimonForsberg Yeah, something along those lines, I'd like. "Less awful" could also work, though possibly too negative

Answer (score 28):

## Because all code can be improved.

<s>Except Jon Skeet's</s>

Comment: Just as long as you don't include the part about Jon Skeet, I'm okay with this one.

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely the non-bold part isn't meant to be part of the  tagline

Comment: Why the "Because"? I prefer *"All code can be improved"*

Comment: @rolfl because.

Comment: I prefer "All code can be improved" as well because it doesn't necessarily refer to CR as a community but also works as a standalone statement.

Answer (score 23):

## Make it work, we'll make it shine

Hints at rule #1 *code must already be working*, and pretty much sums up what we're all about.

Answer (score 17):

## `if (code.isUgly()) { code.review(); }`

As a wink to all those who write code for fun and/or for a living. And I think it reads good enough as English for non-coders to "get it".

Alternative (suggested by [ChrisW](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6434/lets-pick-t-shirt-tagline/6465?noredirect=1#comment14643_6465))

#### `if (code.isUgly) { code.review(); }`

(difference is `isUgly` is a property instead of method)

Comment: Ooh that would look so good on a CR mug!

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes it would!

Comment: Maybe `isUgly` should be a property not a method. Also the villagers are coming with torches and pitchforks to protest your placement of curly braces.

Comment: OK I changed it by removing the extra round braces.

Comment: What's with these ugly braces and semicolon? (Obligatory pythonista comment)

Comment: At least make `isUgly` a function call, because publicly accessible members `isUgly` :)

Comment: I'd go with consistency and stick to the SO mug's `mug.isEmpty()`, so `code.isUgly()` works for me

Comment: @EmilyL. Look at that, I'm getting a code review on my tshirt tagline ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I added both alternatives cuz.

Comment: Does 'Law of Demeter' suggest opportunity for improvement? The `code` appearing twice implies `isUgly` and `review()` could be together, as (private) implementation details of Code, for example `class Code { internal void improve() { while (isUgly) review(); } bool isUgly etc. }`

Comment: Should be `while`

Comment: @nhgrif Should be `while(code){code.review();}`

Comment: `class Code { internal void improve() { while (improveMore()); } bool improveMore() { ...etc... } }`

Comment: Forget `while` loops; make it recursive! Wait, no, then people will just end up on Stack Overflow instead

Comment: @Mat'sMug On my last assignment, it should be *if(true) code.review()*... A bit depressing.

Answer (score 15):

### If it's not broken... fix it anyway

Comment: Maybe "If it's not broke, fix it" would be catchier?

Comment: Maybe. I was just playing off the "if it's not broken don't fix it"

Answer (score 11):

## Does this code make my ass look fat?

([source here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/141/31503) )

Comment: Oh how I want this shirt.

Answer (score 10):

### There's always room for improvement

Credit to @Pops

Answer (score 9):

## Your code... just better

I think the phrase came from somewhere on Meta, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 9):

## `finally { exceptional code }`

Could also be `try { exceptional code }`, or `catch ..` of course, with the former being the most logical. But the above reads better, and has a longer "fuse" before you go "wait, what?" :)

Based on a comment exchange with ChrisW [on this old community ad suggestion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/lets-make-community-ads/1786#1786).

Comment: Except, `finally` runs whether or not... er, whatever. Good one ;-)

Answer (score 8):

## Improving code, bit by bit

I thought I read something similar on the "New Design" post, but couldn't find it.

Comment: I love this.  Especially the pun.

Comment: @Hosch250 It's been almost two days and I still don't get the pun... please, help me out.

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely one bit is 1/8th of a byte, isn't it? And changing something bit by bit is also changing things one step at a time.

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely Code runs on bits and bytes.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Okay then, I did get the pun apparently. I just didn't think it was that funny...

Answer (score 8):

## Leave this code a little better than you found it

Liberally inspired from [Robert Baden-Powell](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Robert_Baden-Powell)

Answer (score 7):

## A community working together for better code

Because that's how I feel :)

Answer (score 6):

## Because every programmer needs a reviewer.

They just might not know it yet.

Answer (score 6):

## Where good code comes to get better

Comment: "*Where **bad** code comes to die*"?

Answer (score 6):

## **{ Brace yourselves }**

One of the most common review remarks.

Comment: ...if you will, with a bit of meme/pop culture reference (*review is coming!*).

Answer (score 5):

## The code cleanup crew

(Make it 30 characters)

Answer (score 4):

## It takes a community to raise a program...

Comment: and it takes one mistake to `raise` an exception (sorry, had to)

Answer (score 4):

^ That there is nothing: no tag line at all, only the `CODE Q REVIEW` logo.

Answer (score 4):

## We can refactor it. We have the technology.

Comment: Don't leave your terminal with an interactive session when marketing might come wandering in.

Comment: @greybeard is this a reference I should be aware of :x

Comment: None that I'm aware of. `We have the technology` rings neither _coder_ nor _reviewer_.

Answer (score 3):

## Helping you code better

It's not really about making the posted code better.
It's really about making the posters write better code in the future.
Teach a man to fish.

Answer (score 2):

## Making your code better

At first I thought "making your (working) code better",
but that's too pedantic, not easy-going enough.
"working" code is kind of implied, no need to mention.

Answer (score 2):

## codereview.stackexchange.com

Perhaps a bit boring though.

Comment: 1. *perhaps*? 2. *a bit*?

Comment: It would be nice if the website URL could be included though...

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely yeah. on the back perhaps?

Comment: I'll vote against a URL on the shirt. It just feels like it'd have more of a business card feel to it, which is a lot less cool than the feel it has now.

Answer (score 2):

### Making code better, together

Answer (score 2):

## Better your code

"Long enough to cover the subject, and short enough to create interest."

Answer (score 2):

## Tough questions, Smart answers

From the old community ad:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Making your code suck less

(tongue-in-cheek)

Answer (score 1):

## Detail-Oreinted Developers

Says it all, I think.

<sub><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub>PS: typo is intentional, stop fixing it ;-)</sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sub>

Comment: @mattsmug oh come on!

Comment: LOL! I totally just... lol

Comment: @jonrsharpe got me as well lol.

Comment: I find the fact that two members here fixed your bug rather apropos for Meta. For a T-shirt slogan, though, not so much.

Answer (score 1):

## We take code seriously

Because those who don't just push and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

## Mission Accomplished

or better, lower case:

## mission accomplished

---

I suggest that, because of [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3778/34757) (plus other reasons which may as well remain nameless)
but an overt reason is that people might be proud of having finished their mission (writing working code), and celebrate that. The T-shirt associates that celebration with taking it to the next level (i.e. code review), and implies that the mission is even more accomplished after code review.

Also, given that "brevity is the soul of wit", like @Paweł said, "it can't be too short". ;-)

Comment: Fun fact: "Brevity is the soul of wit" is a quote from a character who just won't shut up, contradicts himself all the time, uses overly large metaphors, repeats himself constantly, and never stops talking, like a drunk man at a subway or a sober man who's so desperate for company he'll talk to the drunk guy just for a little company.

Comment: You're referring to Shakespeare, are you? ;-)

Comment: Yep! We just finished (re)reading Hamlet in English, and I found myself laughing my ass off (again) when Polonius says "Brevity is the soul of wit" right before launching into a two-dozen-line monologue that could have been summed up as "Yep, Hamlet's crazy. With love for my daughter."

Comment: Paweł said it can't be too short, but I think it could be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## We don't just commit and deploy

Answer (score 0):

## You shall not pass

We used to do this practice of merging your code only when two other devs reviewed it. Not getting aproval... suffer. And it's a fun LOTR line, we being Gandalf-y and all.

Answer (score -2):

## Making working code better

This is how I normally describe what Code Review Stack Exchange is about. It incorporates one of the most important on-topic requirements: The code must be working.

Answer (score -2):

## Code is imperfection which is becoming

Liberally inspired from [Annie Besant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annie_Besant):

> Evil is only imperfection, that which is not complete, which is becoming, but has not yet found its end.

Answer (score -2):

## Code quality police

We crack down on bad code like on minions from hell.

Comment: Kind of make us sound like we strictly enforce programming rules and aren't flexible

Answer (score -2):

## Because you need to know that you don't know what you don't know.

...you know.

Comment: Too confusing I think

Answer (score -2):

## Its not the first version but the code reviewed version that counts...

Comment: Well at least I am in good company with a -1 :-)

Answer (score -2):

### The sweetest sound is silence (at codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score -2):

## Better code reviewed

This is again a short one.

Answer (score -2):

***I've Got The Power!***

& I will not hesitateTo().useIt();

alternative:

I.will(not).hesitateTo().use(it);

Answer (score -3):

**Because computers don't care.**

Answer (score -4):

> I wanted hats but all I got was this shirt

Comment: Not to say the shirt idea is bad, by the way. It's just a nod to Winterbash and a play on a popular quote of "I wanted X but all I got was Y"

Answer (score -4):

## Working code working better

From [rolfl's answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1751/31562) on *"Can/Should our short site description be changed to better reflect what we are about?"*

Answer (score -5):

## Approved

#### or...

## Get your code Approved <sup><sup>(tm)</sup></sup>

Kind of like the tag line in this photo:

[image]

Comment: Picture looks familiar, you may want to add the source.

Answer (score -5):

One for fans of *The Simpsons*:

## Embiggening quality for cromulent code

Answer (score -6):

## Preventing Refuctoring

([definition of refuctoring](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/))

Answer (score -6):

## He who laughs last laughs best

A bit gender-specific but too bad.

This is a mashup of [Loki's suggestion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6470/34757), the [bonhommie](https://www.google.fr/search?q=bonhommie) that exists on this site, and this [canonical metric of code quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1tn6.jpg) except substituting LOL for WTF.

Comment: "They who laugh last laugh best"?  Feel free to use if you decide that you like it.  Also possible with "We" instead of "They".

Comment: I like the "we", well done.

Answer (score -7):

### Never stop improving

Comment: I liked this, but it sounded a little familiar... turns out it's the slogan for Lowe's, the home improvement chain.

Answer (score -7):

**Code not saved. Will be lost :D**
Every code not saved will be lost